# How can I add additional arguments to methods for internal generics?

Tags: r, oop, inheritance, methods, internal

I want to implement an inset method for my class `myClass` for the internal generic `[<-` (~ `help(Extract)`).
This method should run a bunch of tests, before passing on the actual *insetting* off to `[<-` via `NextMethod()`.

I understand that:

- any method has to include at least the arguments of the generic (mine does, I think)
- the `NextMethod()` call does not usually need any arguments (though supplying them manually doesn't seem to help either).

Here's my reprex:

```
x <- c(1,2)
class(x) <- c("myClass", "numeric")

`[<-.myClass` <- function(x, i, j, value, foo = TRUE, ...) {
  if (foo) {
    stop("'foo' must be false!")
  }
  NextMethod()
}

x[1] <- 3  # this errors out with *expected* error message, so dispatch works
x[1, foo = FALSE] <- 3  # this fails with "incorrect number of subscripts
```

What seems to be happening is that `NextMethod()` *also* passes on `foo` to the internal generic `[<-`, which mistakes `foo` for another index, and, consequently errors out (because, in this case, `x` has no second dimension to index on).

I also tried supplying the arguments explicitly no `NextMethod()`, but this also fails (see reprex below the break).

**How can I avoid choking up `NextMethod()` with additional arguments to my method?**

(Bonus: Does anyone know good resources for building methods for internal generics? @Hadleys [adv-r](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#internal-generics) is a bit short on the matter).

---

Reprex with explicit arguments:

```
x <- c(1,2)
class(x) <- c("myClass", "numeric")

`[<-.myClass` <- function(x, i = NULL, j = NULL, value, foo = TRUE, ...) {
  if (foo) {
    stop("'foo' must be false!")
  }
  NextMethod(generic = "`[<-`", object = x, i = i, j = j, value = value, ...)
}

x[1] <- 3  # this errors out with expected error message, so dispatch works
x[1, foo = FALSE] <- 3  # this fails with "incorrect number of subscripts
```

Comment: can't you copy some code of `data.table`? I think that's what they achieved by adding the `,by` statement?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with (the internals of) the *data.table* package. Does it have a ``[<-.data.table`` method? Can you point me to some file in the source where I can find it?

Comment: `data.table` doesn't use `NextMethod` : run this to see the code: `data.table:::'[<-.data.table'`

Comment: search and get inspiration here: `https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table`

Comment: please, keep us up to date with your progress!

Comment: @maxheld do you really need `NextMethod` ? What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: thanks @AndreElrico and @Moody_Mudskipper for the suggestions; I *was* in fact looking for a way with `NextMethod()`, because a) it's elegant/idiomatic and b) I just wanted to better understand how dispatch works for internal generics.
The `data.table:::'[<-.data.table'` solution doesn't use `NextMethod()` as @Moody_Mudskipper pointed out.
*Without* `NextMethod()` I'd just remove class `myClass` from `x`, and then use the generic `[<-`. That would be the easiest workaround in my case.
But, as I said, I wanted to understand `NextMethod()` and don't see why it shouldn't work here.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper what I'm actually trying to accomplish is just to run a bunch of assertions before allowing `[<-` for `myClass`. So I can get this done simply as in the above. I don't really need `NextMethod()` just want to understand why it won't work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see an easy way around this except to strip the class (which makes a copy of `x`)

```
`[<-.myClass` <- function(x, i, value, ..., foo = TRUE) {
  if (foo) {
    cat("hi!")
    x
  } else {
    class_x <- class(x)
    x <- unclass(x)
    x[i] <- value
    class(x) <- class_x
    x
  }
}

x <- structure(1:2, class = "myClass")
x[1] <- 3
#> hi!

x[1, foo = FALSE] <- 3
x
#> [1] 3 2
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "myClass"
```

This is not a general approach - it's only needed for `[`, `[<-`, etc because they don't use the regular rules for argument matching:

> Note that these operations do not match their index arguments in the standard way: argument names are ignored and positional matching only is used. So `m[j = 2, i = 1]` is equivalent to `m[2, 1]` and not to `m[1, 2]`.

(from the "Argument matching" section in `` ?`[` ``)

That means your `x[1, foo = FALSE]` is equivalent to `x[1, FALSE]` and then you get an error message because `x` is not a matrix.

Approaches that don't work:

- Supplying additional arguments to `NextMethod()`: this can only increase the number of arguments, not decrease it
- Unbinding `foo` with `rm(foo)`: this leads to an error about undefined `foo`.
- Replacing `foo` with a missing symbol: this leads to an error that `foo` is not supplied with no default argument.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I understand it, but I don't know so much about that subject so I hope I don't say too many wrong things.

From `?NextMethod`

> NextMethod invokes the next method (determined by the class vector,
>   either of the object supplied to the generic, or of the first argument
>   to the function containing NextMethod if a method was invoked
>   directly).

Your class vector is :

```
x <- c(1,2)
class(x) <- "myClass" # note: you might want class(x) <- c("myClass", class(x))
class(x) # [1] "myClass"
```

So you have no "next method" here, and `[<-.default`, doesn't exist.

What would happen if we define it ?

```
`[<-.default` <- function(x, i, j, value, ...) {print("default"); value} 

x[1, foo = FALSE] <- 3 
# [1] "default"
x
# [1] 3
```

If there was a default method with a `...` argument it would work fine as the `foo` argument would go there, but it's not the case so I believe `NextMethod` just cannot be called as is.

You could do the following to hack around the fact that whatever is called doesn't like to be fed a `foo` argument:

```
`[<-.myClass` <- function(x, i, j, value, foo = FALSE, ...) {
  if (foo) {
    stop("'foo' must be false!")
  }

  `[<-.myClass` <- function(x, i, j, value, ...) NextMethod()
  args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
  args <- args[names(args) %in% c("","x","i","j","value")]
  do.call("[<-",args)
}

x[1, foo = FALSE] <- 3
x
# [1] 3 2
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "myClass"
```

Another example, with a more complex class :

```
library(data.table)
x        <- as.data.table(iris[1:2,1:2])
class(x) <- c("myClass",class(x))

x[1, 2, foo = FALSE] <- 9999
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1:          5.1        9999
# 2:          4.9           3

class(x)
# [1] "myClass"    "data.table" "data.frame"
```

This would fail if the next method had other arguments than `x`, `i`, `j` and `value`, in that case better to be explicit about our additional arguments and run `args <- args[! names(args) %in% c("foo","bar")]`. Then it might work (as long as arguments are given explicitly as `match.call` doesn't catch default arguments). I couldn't test this though as I don't know such method for `[<-`.

Comment: "*So you have no "next method" here, and `[<-.default`, doesn't exist.*"

I don't think *that* is the problem here, but I have updated my above reprex accordingly.
The reason why dispatch on base types works even without class attributes is, I think, part of the design of inherit generics. [Writes](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-and-base-types) @hadley: "*internal generics do not dispatch to methods unless the class attribute has been set (is.object() is true). This means that internal generics do not use the implicit class.*"

So I don't think the "missing" base class is the problem.

Comment: and thanks for `NextMethod()` workaround @Moody_Mudskipper: I'll do something like that.
Still leaving this open until we figure out the reason why `NextMethod()` won't work.

Comment: I updated with an alternate workaround, that doesn't unclass, so a bit cleaner, and it uses `NextMethod`

Comment: Since this is a vector, not a matrix, you can drop the `j` argument and avoid the `do.call()` gymnastics in favour `x[i] <- value`. But I don't know if I'd describe redefining the method inside itself as cleaner 

Comment: It's to keep it general in case OP wants to use the j argument, I said cleaner because it's more general, unclass seemed a bit "brutal", in a general case the object could also have the class data.frame for instance. I agree for OP's precise case.

Comment: I'm not sure that's good practice for `[` since the arguments have such unusual properties (i.e. no matching based on names). We don't have quite enough information here to know if `myClass` is subclassable, but generally I think you should presume it's not, since making subclasses work correctly requires considerable extra thought at all layers on the class implementation.